# Nested breadcrumbs on spartacus

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, spartacus-storefront

I need impement breadcrumbs on nested content pages (e.g: My Account > Order History > Order Details). Spartacus doesn't have this feature by default yet, and isn't planned. Maybe someone know a good approach (workaround) to implement this.

Exists some links on the SAP repo talking about that: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/136 
https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-sto

Comment: You can find more information about that in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984167/is-there-additional-configuration-needed-to-make-the-breadcrumbs-visible-in-a-sp

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned there is no support for such a feature in Spartacus but you could still customize it to have this behavior.

First, make sure make sure your page has a `BreadcrumbComponent` in the `BottomHeaderSlot`. This should be the case as it's the default behavior.

Secondly, as described here ([Is there additional configuration needed to make the breadcrumbs visible in a Spartacus site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984167/is-there-additional-configuration-needed-to-make-the-breadcrumbs-visible-in-a-sp)) you should extend the `ContentPageMetaResolver` to resolve the breadcrumbs like you want.